# getting unbound Local Error even though the variable is defined

Tags: python

```
a = True
b = True
c = True
last_move = 'None'

a1 = 'white'
b1 = 'white'
c1 = 'white'

a2 = 'none'
b2 = 'none'
c2 = 'none'

a3 = 'black'
b3 = 'black'
c3 = 'black'

def calculate(move):

    if move == "a2": a1 = 'none'; a2 = 'white' 
    if move == "b2": b1 = 'none'; b2 = 'white'
    if move == "c2": c1 = 'none'; c2 = 'white'
    if move == "a3": a2 = 'none'; a3 = 'white'
    if move == "b3": b2 = 'none'; b3 = 'white'
    if move == 'c3': c2 = 'none'; c3 = 'white'

    if a2 == 'black' and b1 == 'white': return "axb1"; game_launch()
    if b2 == 'black' and a1 == 'white': return "bxa1"; game_launch()
    if b2 == 'black' and c1 == 'white': return "bxc1"; game_launch()
    if c2 == 'black' and b1 == 'white': return "cxb1"; game_launch()

    if a2 == 'black' and a1 == 'none': return "a1"; game_launch()
    if b2 == 'black' and b1 == 'none' and b == True: print("b1"); game_launch()
    if c2 == 'black' and c1 == 'none': return "c1"; game_launch()
    
    if a3 == 'black' and b2 == 'white': return "axb2"; a1 = 'none'; a = False; b = False; b2 = 'black'; last_move = "axb2"
    if c3 == 'black' and b2 == 'white' and a == True: return "cxb2"; c1 = 'none'; b2 = 'black'; last_move = "cxb2"
    if b3 == 'black' and a2 == 'white': return "bxa2"; b1 = 'none'; a2 = 'black'; last_move = "bxa2"

def game_launch():
    print("launched new game.")

    s = input("type and send a move. ")

    print(calculate(s))

    s = input("type and send a move. ")
        
    print(calculate(s))
```

it asks for a response, when i type b2 i get unbound local error on this line:

`a2 == 'black' and b1 == 'white': return "axb1"; game_launch()`

I don't know what to do because the variables are defined.

the code used to work but after some days I keep getting this error.
it could be visual studio code bug or something.

please help

Comment: If a variable is set anywhere in a function, it is seen as local. Global variables with the same name are ignored. Explicitly declare it as `global`.

Comment: btw All your calls to `game_launch()` like: `return "axb1"; game_launch()` are redundant since the `return` returns and terminates the current function.

Comment: Get rid of all the recursive calls to `game_launch` from `calculate`.  They're unreachable and serve no purpose.  It's also the wrong way to start a new game.  Do it in a loop, not an endless recursive call chain.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple issues here, the main one you're facing being related to how Python handles variable scope.

```
def calculate(move):
    if move == "a2": a1 = 'none'; a2 = 'white' 
    ...
```

When you're assigning values to `a1` and `a2` inside the function, what you're actually doing is declaring new variables, `a1` and `a2`, inside the scope of `calculate`. You can conceptually think of them like `calculate.a1` and `calculate.a2` (although actually trying to use them like that will yield yet more different results in Python).

To remove that ambiguity and use the variables you declared in the global scope (the scope outside any class or function), you use [Python's `global` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-global_stmt), like so:

```
def calculate(move):
    global a, b, c, last_move, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3

    if move == "a2": a1 = 'none'; a2 = 'white' 
    if move == "b2": b1 = 'none'; b2 = 'white'
    if move == "c2": c1 = 'none'; c2 = 'white'
    if move == "a3": a2 = 'none'; a3 = 'white'
    if move == "b3": b2 = 'none'; b3 = 'white'
    if move == 'c3': c2 = 'none'; c3 = 'white'
    ...
```

---

You then also have some logic errors as a result of statement order.

Consider this line:

```
if a2 == 'black' and a1 == 'none': return "a1"; game_launch()
```

Expanded:

```
if a2 == 'black' and a1 == 'none':
    return "a1"
    game_launch()
```

What the return statement does, is terminate the function, and pass (or return) a value back to where the function was called from. The thing to note here is that the termination is immediate, no other logic gets executed after the return statement. So the above is the exact same as this, behavior-wise:

```
if a2 == 'black' and a1 == 'none':
    return "a1"
```

You're then also calling the `game_launch` function recursively. It seems like you're not quite aware of what that does, but suffice it to say, it's not what you want in this case (*even if, admittedly, it would sort of work because of the global state*). Keeping track of whether the game is still running in another variable, and just running a while loop in the `game_launch` function as long as that variable is true is definitely closer to the behavior you're looking for, to keep asking the player for inputs and iteratively calculating the next state from that.

```
# global scope:
state = True

...

def game_launch():
    print("launched new game.")

    while state:
        s = input("type and send a move. ")
        print(calculate(s))
```

You would then set `state` to false once you've reached an end condition. Don't forget to add `state` to the list of variables after the global keyword, if you're going to be setting it from inside `def calculate`.